# Transferring NSF grant to Canadian University

Tags: nsf

I am a postdoc (Canadian citizen) working at a USA university. Me and my postdoc supervisor are planning to apply for a National Science Foundation (NSF) grant (computer science), where I will be the PI.

I am also applying for tenure track (TT) faculty jobs in both USA and Canada. If the NSF grant is awarded to us, and if I get a TT offer from a Canadian university, and decide to join there, can I transfer my cut of the NSF grant to that Canadian institution?

Thanks.

Comment: As the NSF grant overseer.

Comment: Seems unlikely, but ask the NSF or your university's grants office.

Answer (score 3):

It's the National Science Foundation *of the United States*. It generally only funds research in the US unless specific reasons are provided in the rationale of the proposal for why some money should go abroad.

You can always ask the NSF program manager, but you should probably expect them to say no -- because there is really no particular good reason why the NSF should be using American taxpayer money to pay for computer science research in another country.

Comment: "_no particular good reason why the NSF should be using American taxpayer money to pay for […] research in another country_". I'd like to reply "_for the greater good of humankind_", but unfortunately their mission statement contains the word "_nation_" twice: "_To promote the progress of science; to advance the **nation**al health, prosperity, and welfare; and to secure the **nation**al defense; and for other purposes._"

Comment: @Clément From a philosophical point, one can of course take this stance. In practice, this is asking too much of the taxpayers of countries, certainly with regard to a destination like Canada: A country that is undoubtedly rich enough to support research on its own territory. (That aside, the United Nations, OECD, NATO, many private foundations, and many other national and international organizations *do* support research regardless of location.)

Comment: @wolfgangBangerth thanks. NSERC and NSF have a MoU, under which both agencies fund researchers working in US and Canada on collaborative projects. With the Alliance grant, Canadian researchers receive funds from NSERC, and their US counterpart from NSF. May be this is an option for us, if I move back to Canada. (https://www.nserc-crsng.gc.ca/Innovate-Innover/NSERC-NSF-CRSNG_eng.asp)